# PHP Why does this work?

Tags: php, oop

Specifically speaking, why does the below code work (outputs "test").

```
<?
    $variable = 'test';
?>

<?=$variable?>
```

Is this hacky, or functionality?

Comment: they are short tags. `<?=` == `<?php echo`

Comment: PHP is hacky. It's the 21st century and people are still using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?=?>` is a Short Tag for `echo();`
According to [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> Outputs all parameters.
>
> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses.
>
> **echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the
>   opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax
>   only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.**

Gives you the also the next example:

> I have `<?=$foo?>` foo.

Comment: Good deal. Learn new stuff every day. I am curious why a space between <? and = does not work Edit: Thanks for the edit Elias. Neat stuff

Comment: Because, it echo everything after the `=` and if you put a space, it will try to echo, but since is not inside `'` or `"` concadenated to a string, it will fail. It this answer your question, accept this as "best answer"...